# Differences between %.% (dplyr) and %>% (magrittr)

Tags: r, pipe, dplyr, magrittr

The `dplyr` package introduced the `%.%` operator to pass the left hand side as an argument of the function on the right hand side, similar to a *NIX pipe.  The `magrittr` package is a much more lightweight package that exists to define only that pipe-like operator.

Yet one uses `%.%` and the other `%>%`.

**Is there any difference between the two?  Can I just use `%>%` even in `dplyr` code, or will that cause subtle bugs?**

On inspecting the code, they take very different paths early on, so simple eyeball comparison would suggest that they're different.  I haven't been able to find anything documented when I search the web for them, nor have I run across anything in the documentation itself.

Comment: Update: possible answers lurking in the comments here: http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

dplyr now imports `%>%` from magrittr and uses it by default. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23621236/1048186) for details.

---

Differences include

- you can use a `.` as placeholder for the left-hand side, e.g.

  ```
   iris %>% plot(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = .)
  ```
- `%>%` respects `(rhs)`, e.g.

  ```
   1:10 %>% (call("sum"))
   1:10 %>% (function(x) x^2 + 2*x)
  ```

  For a more useful
  example of this, see
  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0c69b019d0b4f6ae5050
- For
  single argument function calls, you can omit parens:

  ```
   "2014-05-18" %>% as.Date
  ```

Answer (score 36):

See the very first item in the current [NEWS](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/blob/master/NEWS.md) file:

> dplyr now imports `%>%` from magrittr (#330). I recommend that you use
>   this instead of `%.%` because it is easier to type (since you can hold
>   down the shift key) and is more flexible

Comment: but now I can see this info and (maybe?) not incur the rtfm "penalty" ?

Comment: SOF is a better vehicle for fuzzy ("I don't even know what exactly the term is for that concept..")  documentation searching

Comment: I would say this should be the new accepted answer because the other one is more or less obsolete at this point.