# Error: could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I'm running an example in R, going through the steps and everything is working so far except for this code produces an error:

```
 words <- dtm %>%
 as.matrix %>%
 colnames %>%
 (function(x) x[nchar(x) < 20])
```

> Error: could not find function "%>%"

I don't understand what the benefit of using this special operator
`%>%` is, and any feedback would be great.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125672/what-does-function-mean-in-r

Comment: I am getting inconsistent results based on the responses. It is failing 8 out of 10 times but then running fine.

Answer (score 214, accepted):

You need to load a package (like `magrittr` or `dplyr`) that defines the function first, then it should work.

```
install.packages("magrittr") # package installations are only needed the first time you use it
install.packages("dplyr")    # alternative installation of the %>%
library(magrittr) # needs to be run every time you start R and want to use %>%
library(dplyr)    # alternatively, this also loads %>%
```

The pipe operator `%>%` was introduced to *"decrease development time and to improve readability and maintainability of code."*

But everybody has to decide for himself if it really fits his workflow and makes things easier.
For more information on  `magrittr`, click [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magrittr/vignettes/magrittr.html).

**Not using the pipe `%>%`, this code would return the same as your code:**

```
words <- colnames(as.matrix(dtm))
words <- words[nchar(words) < 20]
words
```

---

***EDIT:***
(I am extending my answer due to a very useful comment that was made by @Molx)

> Despite being from `magrittr`, the pipe operator is more commonly used
>   with the package `dplyr` (which requires and loads `magrittr`), so
>   whenever you see someone using `%>%` make sure you shouldn't load `dplyr`
>   instead.

Comment: Also do you mean the code written above could be written in different way without the needs to use %>%

Comment: Despite being from `magrittr`, the pipe operator is more commonly used with the package `dplyr` (which requires and loads `magrittr`), so whenever you see someone using `%>%` make sure you shouldn't load `dplyr` instead.

Comment: I would like to stress that only loading Tidyverse (`library(tidyverse)`) might not be enough. I have added (`library(dplyr)`) after `library(tidyverse)` and then `%>%` was found.

Comment: So jelous that this got 171 upvotes. Crazy reputation points

Answer (score 20):

On Windows: if you use %>% inside a %dopar% loop, you have to add a reference to load package `dplyr` (or `magrittr`, which `dplyr` loads).

Example:

```
plots <- foreach(myInput=iterators::iter(plotCount), .packages=c("RODBC", "dplyr")) %dopar%
{
    return(getPlot(myInput))
}
```

If you omit the `.packages` command, and use `%do%` instead to make it all run in a single process, then works fine. The reason is that it all runs in one process, so it doesn't need to specifically load new packages.

Comment: This is a good point and worth highlighting specifically in relation to foreach. I've had issues in the past with this, and it's a different problem to the one solved by the accepted answer.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the right venue to highlight this also, but I've suggested and edit based on the iterators package which simplifies the foreach loop. Feel free to disregard if this is inappropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Saved me. I had no idea I needed to declare the dependencies in the `foreach`.

Answer (score 7):

The pipe operator is not available in base R. You need to load one of the following packages to use it: `dplyr`, `tidyverse` or `magrittr`

Answer (score 4):

One needs to install [`magrittr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) as follows

```
install.packages("magrittr")
```

Then, in one's script, don't forget to add on top

```
library(magrittr)
```

For the meaning of the operator `%>%` you might want to consider [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27125672/7109869): [What does %>% function mean in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27125672/7109869)

Note that the same operator would also work with the library `dplyr`, as it imports from `magrittr`.

`dplyr` used to have a similar operator (`%.%`), which is now deprecated. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621209/differences-between-dplyr-and-magrittr) we can read about the differences between `%.%` (deprecated operator from the library `dplyr`) and `%>%` (operator from `magrittr`, that is also available in `dplyr`)