# dplyr error - could not find function "%>%"

Tags: r, dplyr, magrittr

I am trying to run a line of code in R using the dplyr package.  dplyr is installed and the package appears to have loaded correctly, but does not recognise the %>% function.
The code I am attempting to run is -

```
reptiledata2 = reptiledata %>% filter (START_YEAR>=1980)
```

This leads to the error:

```
Error in reptiledata %>% filter(START_YEAR >= 1980) :    could not find function "%>%"
```

This code has previously worked for me before, but for some reason is not working today. Have also tried to load *magrittr* package but this does not solve the issue either.

Comment: Or this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248583/error-could-not-find-function/30248632

Answer (score 0):

Install or reinstall dplyr package. 
`install.packages("dplyr")`

If does not work, try to remove it and reinstall.