# Execution Halted for Project

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am supposed to plot data pertaining to the "movies" dataset, and I must utilize Rmarkdown and convert my work into a PDF. When I try to render my work, I receive the following error message:

```
processing file: DAT-301-Lab-2.Rmd
  |...........................                        |  52% [unnamed-chunk-6] 
Quitting from lines 56-80 [unnamed-chunk-6] (DAT-301-Lab-2.Rmd)
                                                                                                             
Error in `movies %>% select(Action, Animation, Comedy, Drama, Documentary, Romance, Short) %>%
    colSums()`:
! could not find function "%>%"
Execution halted
```

The lines it is referring to are as follows:

```
#5) How many movies of each genre (action, animation, comedy, drama, documentary, romance, short) are
there in this data base? (use a bar plot)

genre_counts <- movies %>% select(Action, Animation, Comedy, Drama, Documentary, Romance, Short) %>%colSums()  # Sum the number of movies in each genre


# Plot the counts using a bar plot
 count <- barplot(genre_counts,
        main = "Movies by Genre",
        xlab = "Genre",
        ylab = "Number of Movies",
        col = "blue", 
        )
colSums(count)

#Each genre varied in their number movies. The results are as follows:
#Action -       4688
#Comedy -      17271 
#Animation -    3690
#Comedy -      17271
#Drama -       21811
#Documentary -  3472
#Romance -      4744
#Short -        9458
```

I am not sure what is wrong. It is worth mentioning I did look up to see if anyone else online has had a similar problem. I found some, but it did not work. I already downloaded Rtools (Version 4.3) and the following packages:

```
install.packages("magrittr") # package installations are only needed the first time you use it
install.packages("dplyr")    # alternative installation of the %>%
library(magrittr) # needs to be run every time you start R and want to use %>%
library(dplyr)    # alternatively, this also loads %>%
devtools::install_github("edzer/sp")
```

Despite these already being downloaded before I attempted to render it, I still receive the same error message.

I already tried downloading the following code:

```
install.packages("magrittr") # package installations are only needed the first time you use it
install.packages("dplyr")    # alternative installation of the %>%
library(magrittr) # needs to be run every time you start R and want to use %>%
library(dplyr)    # alternatively, this also loads %>%
devtools::install_github("edzer/sp")
```

It did not work and I still receive the same error message:

```
processing file: DAT-301-Lab-2.Rmd
  |...........................                        |  52% [unnamed-chunk-6] 
Quitting from lines 56-80 [unnamed-chunk-6] (DAT-301-Lab-2.Rmd)
                                                                                                             
Error in `movies %>% select(Action, Animation, Comedy, Drama, Documentary, Romance, Short) %>%
    colSums()`:
! could not find function "%>%"
Execution halted
```

I am trying to render my work into a PDF; I am using Rmarkdown.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: could not find function "%>%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248583/error-could-not-find-function) - make sure that you run `library(dplyr)` in the rmd file you are trying to render, rather than in a separate R script.

Comment: Ffffjjjjjjjjjjj