# Percentage (%) calculation of a dataset, but i keep getting error messages

Tags: r, percentage

I have been trying to calculate the percentage (%) of a dataset, but i keep getting error messages. I need to get the percentages so i can move further to create a Pie chart, but I've been stuck on the percentage part for a couple of days. I watched youtube videos, and i tried the methods i could find both they are both giving me error messages in R

I'll have both average methods listed below, as i only need one of them to work.

**First Average Method**

```
 perc_avgerage_activity_sleep <-average_activity_sleep %>%
  group_by(activity_level)%>%
  mutate(perc = avg_steps/sum(avg_steps))*100
  as.data.frame()
```

**This is the output to the code above**

Error in average_activity_sleep %>% group_by(activity_level) %>% mutate(perc = avg_steps/sum(avg_steps)) :
could not find function "%>%"

**Second Average Method**

```
transform(average_activity_sleep, perc = ave(avg_steps, activity_level,
                                             FUN.prop.table))
```

**This is the second output**

```
Error in eval(substitute(list(...)), `_data`, parent.frame()) :
object 'FUN.prop.table' not found
```

Comment: You need to have the `dplyr` package installed and loaded e.g. `library(dplyr)` in order to use the code in your first attempt. Also, `as.data.frame()` can be deleted.

Comment: I just noticed you have no closing bracket on your `mutate()`. Unclosed functions can throw the error you got. Try `mutate(perc = avg_steps/sum(avg_steps)*100)` instead

Answer (score 0):

Regarding part 1 of your question:
following another question ([Error: could not find function "%>%"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30248583/error-could-not-find-function)) loading packages `magrittr` or `dplyr` might solve the missing `%>%` function.

Regarding part 2 of your question:
does the `ave(...)` function work outside the `transform(..)` function? Does the `FUN.prop.table` function work outside of `ave(..)`? I would test that first.

Comment: Thanks, i have dplyr loaded already. I also tried installing and loading magrittr as you suggested, but i got the following error message after i installed magrittr                                                                                                               
Error in mutate(., perc = avg_steps/sum(avg_steps)) :   could not find function "mutate"                                                                                                                                     Part 2: I tried the average without the FUN, and i got : Error: object 'FUN.prop.table' not found.